# Bootstrap navigation - external link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, navigation

I got a problem with external link in my navbar.

I have added "German" to the navbar. By clicking, it should open an new window to get to the german version of the site (in this example it's google). But nothing happens.

Here is my test url: http://cc2.ngabriel.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide a jsfiddle which describe the problem, or at least some code in your question,instead of a link to your website. More explanation here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Open the console of your browser (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, depending your browser) and you'll see that your javascript launch an exception in custom.js at line 296:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
```

On this code:

```
overlay = document.querySelector( 'div#login' ),
closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
```

`overlay` is undefined because you don't have a `div` with a `login` id in your DOM.